# I forget my ubuntu password

Tags: ubuntu, ssh

I have one **ubuntu 16.04** server.The username is **yasin**. I want to ssh to it by

```
ssh yasin@192.168.122.29
```

It asked me a password.I think i forget the password because i try everything in my mind.

It is on **baremetal** and i **can not reboot** it to change password. what should i do?

I can not login as root also.
I do not have key.
yasin is the only user.

**I can not reboot it.**

Comment: If you log in as `root`, you can use the `passwd` utility to change any user's password to a known value.

Comment: i can not log in as root.i disable the root login.

Comment: Is `yasin` the only user you have on that machine?

Comment: how i can modify it?

Comment: yasin is the only user

Comment: You seem to have put yourself into a position from which you can't recover. There may be things you can do if you remove the boot disc from the server (see `chroot`); if you can't do that, then you will probably need to create the server again. As a server, it should have a regular back-up schedule, so you should not lose anything, though it will take some time to restore.

Comment: every thing in computer world have a solution.but we did not know that.

Answer (score -1):

If there is no other user account accessible via ssh there is no other way than to reboot. Look here [in askubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/24006/how-do-i-reset-a-lost-administrative-password).
If your server is with a hosting company there should be a way to access the boot menu.

Comment: i can not reboot it. there is redis on it. i can not reboot.

Comment: So you are afraid your data could be corrupted by turning off power? It should gracefully shut down via acpi by pressing the power button. If you cannot do this with an web interface from your hoster ask their support.